# In a bokeh plot with two seperate y-axes, how can I zoom on y-axis and keep the second fixed?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have created a bokeh plot with two lines in one plot. I have also created two separate y-axes making use of extra_y_ranges and Range1d.

I can set the initial range of each y-axis. When I use the zoom wheel, it affects both y-axes but I want to only change one of them and not both.

I even tried setting separate renderers, as follows but still failed to achieve the goal.

```
plot1.y_range.renderers=[line1]
plot1.extra_y_ranges.renderers=[line2]
```

Can anyone help me get a separate y-axis zoom level? i.e. only zoom in one line while keeping the other one constant. Thanks.

P.S. My code uses add_periodic_callback to update the plot in real-time based on a DB if that makes any difference.

Comment: Pleas check the [twin axis example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/axes/twin_axes.html) which shows you how the three [zoom options](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.WheelZoomTool.zoom_together) `"all"` (default), `"cross"` and `"none"` of the `"WheelZoomTool"` are working. Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be doing what I exactly want to do. I will try and implement it in my code and see how it works. Thank you very much for your help and happy holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link mentioned by @mosc9575 works perfectly. Thanks.